# Is there anything in here that would explain why the system process is using 8.5 GB of ram

Tags: windows-10, memory

[image: Poolmon Results]

I don't have much more to say other than system is using 8.5GB and this cause games and other programs go into the pagefile and slow down

Comment: What's the machine's uptime?

Comment: System allocates the 12gb of ram on startup then it releases to around 8

Answer (score 0):

There was a program(ImDisk) running that created a ramdisk, I must have enable it to run at startup by accident